# How to get label name by labelId using GMAIL API

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I am succesfully taking the labelids of all assigned labels to the specific mail:

```
var emailInfoRequest = gmailService.Users.Messages.Get(MigrationToolConstants.userIdString, mailId); 
var emailInfoResponse = emailInfoRequest.ExecuteAsync();
emailInfoResponse.Wait();
emailInfoResponse.Result.LabelIds
```

But the labels which I created manually are receiving labelid: label_1, label_2 etc.. instead of their name as a labelId

But the service mails are with labelId - name of the label, for example: "INBOX".

So in my object I need to store all the labels which are assigned to the certain mail. Is there a way not to do the check with 2 loops for checking is the labelId matches with the labelLists of the user in order to take the name of the label, because I really need to safe additional checks, because of time issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var labelId in emailInfoResponse.Result.LabelIds)
{
  foreach (var label in labels)
  {
    if (labelId == label.Id)
    {
      //Do smth
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is one way of doing it, but if there is a short way with which I can win some time would be awesome